# How to print PostOrder and PreOrder by using TreeNode?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

So I been working on this TreeNode program and I couldn't figure out how to print the PostOrder and PreOrder. I got the inOrder correct, but couldn't figure out the rest of the code for PreOrder and PostOrder.

Here my code for inOrder for TreeNode:

```
public static <T> void inOrder(TNode<T> node) {
        if (node.getLeft() != null)
        inOrder(node.getLeft());

    System.out.print(node.getData() + " ");

    if (node.getRight() != null)
        inOrder(node.getRight());

}
```

Comment: You can refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Answer (score 0):

```
preOrder(node) {
  print(node);
  preOrder(node.left);
  preOrder(node.right);
}

postOrder(node) {
  postOrder(node.left);
  postOrder(node.right);
  print(node);  
}
```

Comment: It would help if you explained the code at least a little bit; and also, there is a problem here because your `postOrder` method makes its calls to `preOrder`.

Comment: This is a basic description of the algorithm. If he doesn't understand it, it's because he slept through his class.

Comment: @LowKeyEnergy SO isn't for those who were awaking in the classroom but also for them who didn't even have a classroom! it would be better whatever you are posting please give some description about it.